# Speed up sed replacement string read from a file

Tags: bash, sed

First time posting, so please be kind. I am reading through the file "bar" one line at a time and using sed to replace every other line in "foo" (starting with the first line) with the line read from "bar". The code below works, but it is painfully slow when "foo" is 48,890 lines and "bar" is ~24,445 lines (exactly half foo's length).

Does anyone have a recommendation on how to speed this process up?

```
x=1
while read i;do
  sed -i "$x s/^.*$/$i/" foo
  x=$[$x +2]
done < bar
```

Comment: Does it have to be done using `sed`? `awk` or `perl` would be better.

Comment: Completely rewriting `foo` every time you read a line from `bar` is *of course* going to be slow.

Comment: BTW, `$[ ]` is literally 1970s-era syntax. Since the early 1990s, when the POSIX sh standard was published, `$(( ))` has been the correct syntax for entering a math context in shell. While bash also supports `$[ ]`, many purely POSIX shells (ash, dash, etc) support only `$(( ))`.

Comment: Thanks for heads up on `$(())` @Charles Duffy

Answer (score 6):

Interleaving with `paste` and awk:

```
paste -d '\n' bar <(awk 'NR%2==0' foo)
```

or, if process substitution is not available:

```
awk 'NR%2==0' foo | paste -d '\n' bar -
```

To replace `foo`:

```
paste -d '\n' bar <(awk 'NR%2==0' foo) > tmp && mv tmp foo
```

or

```
awk 'NR%2==0' foo | paste -d '\n' bar - > tmp && mv tmp foo
```

---

I benchmarked a little (just execution time, ignoring memory requirements).

Create input files (about ten times larger than in the question):

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom count=500000 | tr -cd [:alpha:] | fold -w 100 |
> sed 's/^/foo /' > foo
$ dd if=/dev/urandom count=250000 | tr -cd [:alpha:] | fold -w 100 |
> sed 's/^/bar /' > bar
$ wc -l foo bar
  539994 foo
  270126 bar
  810120 total
```

I used `time` to measure execution time. All solutions had their output redirected to a new file. Results in seconds, averaged over five tries each:

```
codeforester            9.878
codeforester, mapfile   8.072
Fred                   17.332
Charles Duffy          'Argument list too long"
Claude                 27.448
Barmar                  0.298
Benjamin W.             0.176
```

Charles' also blew up with input at 10% of the size used here.

Comment: Really appreciate your benchmark!  I am surprised that @fred's solution turns out to be slow. BTW, there was bug in my code that would result in blank lines being output because I wasn't checking for size of bar file.  Fixed it.  Just a small issue with your solutions -- all of them output a blank line at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your thoroughness! @Benjamin W.

Comment: `paste -d '\n' bar <(awk 'NR%2==0' foo) > tmp && mv tmp foo` worked like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

Here's an `awk` solution. It reads all of `bar` into an array. When it's reading `foo`, it prints the line or the next element of this array depending on whether it's an odd or even line number.

```
awk 'BEGIN {index1 = 1}
     FNR == NR {file1[NR] = $0; next}
     NR % 2 == 1 { print file1[index1++]; next }
     { print }' bar foo > newfoo
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the slowness in your current solution is caused by a huge number of forks needed for `sed` as well as heavy I/O caused by repeated rewrite of your file.  Here is a pure Bash solution with zero forks:

```
#!/bin/bash

# read "bar" file into an array - this should take less memory than "foo"
while read -r line; do
  bar_array+=("$line")
done < bar


# traverse "foo" file and replace odd lines with the lines from "bar"
# we don't need to read the whole file into memory
i=0
max_bar="${#bar_array[@]}"
while read -r line; do
  #
  # we look at bar_array only when we are within the limits of that file
  #
  p="$line"
  if ((i < max_bar && i % 2 == 0)); then
    p=${bar_array[$i]}
  fi
  printf "%s\n" "$p"
  ((i++))
done < foo
```

---

Example run:

bar's content:

```
11
22
33
44
55
```

foo's content:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Output:

```
11
2
33
4
55
6
7
8
```

---

With Bash 4 and above, the read statement

```
while read -r line; do
  bar_array+=("$line")
done < bar
```

can also be written as:

```
mapfile -t bar_array < bar
```

Comment: `file1+=( "$line" )`, to avoid string-splitting and globbing. You could also `mapfile -t file1 <file1`, or `IFS=$'\n' read -r -a file1 < file1`, to avoid the explicit loop for the read.

Comment: How easy to forget the basic lessons all the while asking others to follow.  Corrected it, thanks @CharlesDuffy.

Comment: If anyone likes this solution, they need to thank the brilliance of SO members like Charles Duffy and @barmar.  I am learning so much from them everyday.

Comment: (...I should have qualified that: The `mapfile` approach is bash 4 or newer, so if compatibility with 3.x is needed then there can be a good reason to stick with `read`).

Comment: (aside, while we're giving credit: all I know about bash, I learned from greycat on the freenode #bash IRC channel)

Answer (score 1):

Other answers suggest approaches based on storing whole files in arrays.  This will have some practical limitations at some point depending on file size.

One other way is to simply read from both files, one line at a time, opening them in separate file descriptors.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3< foo
exec 4< bar

eof_bar=0
eof_foo=0

while [[ $eof_bar = 0 ]]
do
   # Foo line we keep
   IFS= read -r -u 3 foo_line || eof_foo=$?
   [[ "$eof_foo" != 0 ]] || [[ -n "$foo_line" ]] || break
   printf "%s\n" "$foo_line"
   # Bar line we will replace with
   IFS= read -r -u 4 bar_line || eof_bar=$?
   [[ "$eof_bar" = 0 ]] || [[ -n "$bar_line" ]] || break
   # Foo line we skip (line from bar was present)
   IFS= read -r -u 3 foo_line
   [[ "$eof_foo" != 0 ]] || [[ -n "$foo_line" ]] || break
   # Actual replacement (both files had required lines)
   printf "%s\n" "$bar_line"
done

# Cat the rest of the lines from foo (if any), if bar did not
# have enough lines compared to foo
cat <&3

# Close file descriptors
exec 3>&-
exec 4>&-
```

The code reads two lines from `foo` for each line from `bar`, and simply skips printing the second line from `foo` that is read at each iteration.

Doing it this way will use very little memory, so files of arbitrary size can be handled.

Comment: Looks a little complex but I appreciate your effort to make it I/O efficient! I think it prints a few blank lines for the example in my answer.

Comment: Wonder why this performs poorly in @BenjaminW.'s experiment.

Comment: @codeforrester  It probably is a mix of (1) Bash not being especially fast, to be polite (2) array-based solutions being faster as long as there is enough memory, that old space/time tradeoff (3) me not being especially versed in optimizing for speed.  I wonder what kind of buffering is done on files open for redirection from file descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

awk seems the best alternative because it doesn't create sub shell at each line for reading, it take all the files in one process with few modification/complication for it

```
# Oneliner for batch or command line
awk 'FNR==NR{b[NR]=$0;next}{if(NR%2==1)$0=b[((NR+1)/2)];print}' bar foo
```

*Same* code but self commented for understanding

```
awk '# when reading first file (bar)
     FNR == NR {
        # load line content into an array
        bar[ NR] = $0
        # cycle to next line (don't go further in the code for this input line)
        next
        }

     # every line from other files (only foo here)
     {
        # every odd line, replace content with corresponding array content
        # NR = record line and is odd so (NR + 1) / 2 -> half the line number uprounded
        if (NR % 2 == 1) $0 = bar [ ( ( NR + 1 ) / 2)]

        # print the line (modified or not)
        print
     }
    ' bar foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Run all your `sed` commands in one invocation, and you rewrite `foo` only once, instead of rewriting it once per line of `bar`.

```
x=1
sed_exprs=( )
while IFS= read -r i; do
  sed_exprs+=( -e "$x s/^.*$/$i/" )
  x=$(( x + 2 ))
done < bar

sed "${sed_exprs[@]}" -i foo
```

Comment: Will launching `sed` with tens of thousands of arguments fail or introduce unexpected performance bottlenecks?

Comment: It'll fail if the combined length goes over ARG_MAX. Might be slow, too, depending on implementation details.

Comment: Do you know what would be a typical value for ARG_MAX?

Comment: Usually something like 64k on modern systems, but combined length of environment variables counts against it too.

Comment: Honestly, I'd go with codeforester's solution on this one.

Comment: codeforester's solution also loads the whole content of the file in memory (array), which probably has limits higher than arguments, but will still choke at some point (I have no idea how efficient or memory intensive shell arrays are).  I have suggested a solution that reads from both files and simply skips lines in `foo`, and would have no practical file size limitations.

Comment: To be clear, I'm keeping this around because it's potentially useful to other folks trying to coalesce a much smaller set of changes into a single `sed` command, whereas many of the other answers are very specialized for the OP's exact situation but not necessarily likely to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a streaming solution that can work using small constant memory, in case you have really huge files on a machine with little RAM.

```
#!/bin/bash

# duplicate lines in bar to standard output
paste -d '\n' bar bar |

# pair line-by-line foo with lines from previous command
paste -d '|' foo - |

# now the stream is like:
#  foo line 1|bar line 1
#  foo line 2|bar line 1
#  foo line 3|bar line 2
#  foo line 4|bar line 2
#  foo line 5|bar line 3
#  ...
{
  # set field separator to correspond with previous paste delimiter
  IFS='|'
  # read pairs of lines, discarding the second
  while read -r foo bar && read -r junk
  do
    # print the odd lines from foo
    printf "%s\n" "$foo"
    # interleaved with the lines from bar
    printf "%s\n" "$bar"
  done
}
```

You have to choose a delimiter (here `|`) that doesn't occur in `foo`.  Tested with:

```
paste (GNU coreutils) 8.26
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a heavily modified version of my first answer, which I am posting separately following the benchmarks submitted.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3< foo
exec 4< bar
eof=0
IFS=
n=$'\n'
while :
do
   readarray -n 2 -u 3 fl && read -r -u 4 bl || break
   echo "${fl[1]}$bl"
done
# Add remaining data
[[ -n ${fl[1]} ]] || echo "$fl"
[[ -n $bl ]] || echo "$bl"
# Cat the rest of the lines from foo (if any), if bar did not
# have enough lines compared to foo
cat <&3
# Close file descriptors
exec 3>&-
exec 4>&-
```

Turns out my "hand optimized" solution is simpler and more readable than my first version, which goes to show that thinking about speed sometimes brings about simplification, which is always good.

On my machine, the test for my first answer runs in about the same time as for the benchmark, and with this new answer in a bit less than 7 seconds, which is considerably quicker, but nothing as fast as the `awk` solution, of course.

**EDIT**

I replaced the two reads in "foo" by one readarray, which reduced run time (on my machine) from about 9 seconds to below 7, more than I would have thought.  This leads me to think significant improvements could be made by reading both files in arrays (but not the whole file to avoid the risk of hitting memory limits), at the cost of additional code complexity, obviously.